# Nested conditional search and in-place substituition

Tags: awk

I'm an awk newbie. I have a file that looks like:

```
beans and celery  
beans and oatmeal  
beans and beans  
quinoa
<fo:external-graphic width="auto" height="auto" content-width="36pt" src="url(file:/C:/Users/xxx/images/tip.svg)"/>
<fo:external-graphic src="url(images/image1.png)" width="6.3in" height="auto" content-width="246px" content-height="322px"/>
```

I'm trying to perform a search and replace in-place for the "fo" tag. I want to capture the beginning of the tag, as well as the "src" parameter. Please note that the position of the src tag varies from line to line!

I've been able to get the fields I want using the following:

```
awk '/<fo:external-graphic.*/ {for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {if ($i ~ "src") print $1 " " $i}}' inventory.txt
```

How can I do an in-place substitution of this? 
I also want to append a string to new contents of the line. I've tried:

```
awk '/<fo:external-graphic.*/ {for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {if ($i ~ "src") print $1 " " $i "misc stuff here"}}' inventory.txt
```

But it completely messes up the order of the resulting string, which I want to be of the form:

```
<fo:external-graphic src="url(images/image1.png)" misc stuff here
```

PS1: 
Further clarification about what result I want:
The file contains strings like:

```
<fo:external-graphic width="auto" height="auto" content-width="36pt" src="url(file:/C:/Users/xxx/images/tip.svg)"/>
<fo:external-graphic src="url(images/image1.png)" width="6.3in" height="auto" content-width="246px" content-height="322px"/>
```

I want to process these in and get an output like:

```
<fo:external-graphic src="url(images/image1.png)" _completely new stuff here, till end of string_ />
```

for example:

```
<fo:external-graphic src="url(images/image1.png)" age="25" sex="M" />
```

I want the result to ALWAYS begin with:

```
<fo:external-graphic src="url(images/image1.png)"
```

then the extra stuff eg:

```
age="25" sex="M" />
```

No other part of the original string is needed in the final output.

PS2: Can I pack all this into a gsub? To the best of my knowledge, gsub only take two arguments. I've tried to make a complex expression, for the replace argument, but it keeps failing eg:

```
gawk '/<fo:external-graphic.*/ {for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {if ($i ~ "src") gsub($0, "boy band"); {print}}}' inventory.txt > testres
```

PS3: This is just a newbie observation, maybe I'm wrong. Consider a file with the following contents:

```
Donald Trump
Donald Duck
George Bush
Steve Austin
```

The regexp to search for all lines that begin with Donald is:

```
/^Donald/
```

If I want to replace all occurrences of "Donald" with "Barrack", I could do the following:

```
gawk -i inplace '{ gsub(/^Donald/, "Barrack"); { print } }' FILENAME
```

If I want to **completely change** all lines that contain "Donald" I would do:

```
gawk -i inplace '{ gsub(/^Donald.*/, "Barrack"); { print } }' FILENAME
```

gawk and gsub appear to only replace the span or whatever part of the string matches the given regexp. Thus if I want to completely change a whole line, my regexp should span the whole of that line.

PS4: Just to clear any ambiguities about the solution I expect. Given the following file:

```
<fo:external-graphic width="auto" height="auto" content-width="36pt" src="url(file:/C:/Users/xxx/images/tip.svg)"/>
<fo:external-graphic width="6.3in" height="auto" src="url(images/image1.png)" content-width="246px" content-height="322px"/>
<fo:external-graphic src="url(images/image1.png)" width="6.3in" content-width="246px" content-height="322px"/>
```

I'm looking for an awk/gawk solution that will replace this file with:

```
<fo:external-graphic src="url(file:/C:/Users/xxx/images/tip.svg)" age="25" sex="M" />
<fo:external-graphic src="url(images/image1.png)" age="25" sex="M"/>
<fo:external-graphic src="url(images/image1.png)" age="25" sex="M"/>
```

The target file **must be changed**.

Comment: @Inian It doesn't appear to update the file. Please see the my updated question to see the form I expect for the final answer!

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Please see the latest update to my question! If you have any doubts, let me know. Thanks

Comment: @Inian Please see the latest update to my question! If you have any doubts, let me know. Thanks

Comment: My last update should fix your problem

Answer (score 2):

Your attempt is right, but assuming your intention is add only on the word starting with `src` i.e. on `$i`, apply the action only for that field, and keep the other fields as-is

```
awk '/<fo:external-graphic.*/ {for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {if ($i ~ "src") $i = $i " misc stuff here"}}1' inventory.txt
```

The part `$i = $i " misc stuff here"` does action of appending the string only on the fields matching your regex condition. Notice the removal of `print` and appending of `{..}1` at the end. What that basically means is re-construct the whole line based on the modifications done inside `{..}`. Since we are modifying only certain fields, the other ones are kept intact.

If you want to re-write the entire field starting with `src` and append some string, use a proper regex match with `gsub()` and append string after the matched text denoted by `&`

```
awk '/<fo:external-graphic.*/ {for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) { if ($i ~ "src") gsub(/src=\"url([^"]*)\"/, "& new string", $i ) }}1' inventory.txt
```

From OP's most recent edit, it seems OP just wants the `src` field modified with new string to be appended at the end. The rest of the fields can be ignored it seems.  Using `match()` on GNU `awk` has an added advantage of adding a third parameter to store the captured groups as

```
awk -v newstr="age=\"25\" sex=\"M\"" 'match($0, /^(<fo:external-graphic).*(src=\"url([^"]*)\").*(\/>)$/, arr){ print arr[1]" "arr[2]" "newstr""arr[4]  }' file
```

Note that GNU `awk` did not have in-place modifications up until 4.1.2, on which you can just do

```
gawk -i inplace '{...}' inventory.txt
```

For versions earlier to that, use a temporary file

```
awk '{...}' inventory.txt > tmpfile && mv tmpfile inventory.txt
```

Or if you `moreutils` installed, use `sponge` to slurp the output from the first command and re-create the file back with the latest.

```
awk '{...}' inventory.txt | sponge inventory.txt
```

---

From your sample text on the question, one can't recognize if its some markup language of sorts (XML, HTML). If its a proper syntax aware language, then you should use a parser that knows that grammar.

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT3:*** Adding one more code here as per OP's new edit.

```
awk  '
/ width.*content-width.*src/{
  sub(/ width.*content-width.*src/," src")
  sub(/\/>$/," age=\"25\" sex=\"M\"&")
}
/src.*width/{
  match($0,/src[^)]*/)
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH+2)
  sub(/src.*/,"")
  $0=$0 OFS val OFS "age=\"25\" sex=\"M\"/>"
}
1
'  Input_file
```

---

---

***EDIT2:*** For changing complete line with respect to OP's PS3 could you please try following.

```
awk '/^Donald/{$0="new_line_value"} 1'  Input_file
new_line_value
new_line_value
George Bush
Steve Austin
```

---

---

***EDIT:*** Since OP has changed expected output so adding solution as per that output now too.

```
awk '/^<fo:external-graphic src=.*/ && match($0,/src=.*\)\"/){$0=substr($0,1,RSTART+RLENGTH) " new_value_bla_bla_here.. />"} 1' Input_file
```

---

---

Could you please try following(haven't tested it thoroughly since your expected output is not clear).

```
awk '
/^<fo:/ && match($0,/src=.*>/){
  $0=substr($0,1,RSTART-1) OFS "new_value_here.." OFS substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH+1)
}
1
'  Input_file
```

In this code checking a line which starts from `<fo:` string and then trying to catch string from `src=` till `/` by `match` and replacing that captured text with new string here.

In case you want to save output into Input_file itself then append `> temp_file  && mv temp_file  Input_file` in above code too.

Comment: The second line is ok. The first line prints out: <fo:external-graphic width="auto" height="auto" content-width="36pt" src="url(file:/C:/Users/xxx/images/tip.svg)"/ new_value_bla_bla_here.. />. Please feel free to test your solution against the file I provided at the beginning of my question

Comment: @user1801060, check now and let me know then? I was not checking condition for string `^<fo:external-graphic src=`  check now once?

Comment: Perhaps the mistake is mine. Here's a screenshot of my result: https://imgur.com/aENVTyD

Comment: @user1801060, is it like all `src` you want to match or any specific string you want it to do?

Comment: PS: I have an idea of what's wrong. The regexp should span the whole line, if you want to completely change a whole line.

Comment: @user1801060, please give an example here in code tags in comments itself.

Comment: @user1801060, I still think your expected output is not clear still give a SIMPLE example of input lines and expected output lines keep it simple.

Comment: See PS3 in my update to the question. I want to change the WHOLE line, not part of it.

Comment: @user1801060, ok try this one as a starting point `awk '/^Donald/{$0="new_line_value"} 1' ` will update this in post too.

Comment: @user1801060, check my EDIT2 now and let me know then?

Comment: @user1801060, for inplace updating Input_file I have already given you the trick where you are NOT dependent on `awk`'s version.

Comment: It works for the Donald example. Can we please make it work for the file referred to in the first line of the question that is the file containing "..fo:external-graphic.."

Comment: @user1801060, it should be more or less same(if you take regex from my already given codes) `awk 'match($0,/^<fo:external-graphic src=\".*/){$0="Give here your new VALUE"} 1'  Input_file`  OR you could try to combine this `awk` with my given ones too to apply multiple different conditions in your requirements, Let me know now?

Comment: @user1801060, could you please check my new code EDIT3 now and let me know?

Comment: Great effort! The first one didn't work, the last two worked. I believe getting a regexp to work for all variants is the problem. I'll have a look at it tomorrow.